# NSData return nil when parse html

Tags: ios, objective-c, url, web-scraping, nsdata

I want to get some information from this website "http://phim14.net/".
I use this code :

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://phim14.net/"];
     NSError *error;
     NSData *htmlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url options:NSDataReadingUncached error:&error];
     TFHpple *parser = [TFHpple hppleWithHTMLData:htmlData];
```

At the beginning this code is working and I can get some info. But after several times trying I met an error that "htmlData" was return nil, so I think the website was down but I can connect to that webpage using Firefox. I try to parse other website but it's still ok? 
I try to print out the error and it said that

```
`"error NSError *   domain: @"NSCocoaErrorDomain" - code: 256   0x00007fbb224023c0"`
```

Someone please help me figure out what is the problem??

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10106087/nscocoaerrordomain-code-256

Comment: actually it's not the same please read my question

Answer (score 0):

It seems `errorcode 256` doesn't have much description. So for safe way to get data from `URL`,  use this method 
`sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse:error:` from `NSURLConnection`.

```
NSData* data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:30] returningResponse:nil error:&error];
```

Also please check these [answer1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21961737/1866077), [answer2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22269629/1866077)

Answer (score -1):

Your URL is missing the scheme: "**http://**" and this is giving you the error:

```
Error -> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=256
```

Try adding this to the URL and it should work.